# Subordinating Conjunctions and Conjunctive adverbs

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

Is there way to identify which words are Subordinating Conjunctions and which are Conjunctive adverbs, or do we need to memorize it? Both seems similar to me

```
Subordinating Conjunctions: Although, Because, While etc.
Conjunctive adverbs: Also, Finally, Similarly, Moreover etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a conjunctive adverb begins a sentence, it uses a comma. Hence, try to start a sentence with the word. If you can pause after using it, it's a conjunctive adverb.

For example:

- Buses are an easy form of transport in the city. Similarly, trains are convenient, but they have less stops.

However, if you use a subordinate conjunction like "although" you don't use a pause or comma.

For example:

- Although trains are easy to catch in the city, they offer fewer stops than buses.

Look at examples on this site http://www2.estrellamountain.edu/faculty/stonebrink/ESL032/conjunction2/conjunction2.html
and you will see the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this page about "conjunctive adverb": http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/conjunctiveadverb.htm

and this about "subordinating conjunction": http://chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateconjunction.htm

I wouldn't advise you to memorize them.  For me, the best way to determine them is to know and understand their function.

Let's take for example the word "after."  As used in a sentence with another word or other words, it is neither just a preposition nor an adverb nor a conjunction. It depends on how it is used or how it functions when used in a sentence. To illustrate this advice, please see below:

As preposition:  *after* eating, *after* today, *after* work

As adverb:  graduated the year *after*, see you *after*

As conjunction:  *after* she left, *after* I had eaten, *after* I attended the meeting

Comment: I wish I knew why my answer was voted down... so I could improve next time.  Is my answer wrong?

Comment: Don't know the reason. You should not add those link at the beginning; They didn't ask for the list, or you better add it at the end. It is hard to understand the example you have given; Give full sentence.